# Database url in jmeter?

Tags: jdbc, jmeter

I have a database stored at a server. I want to load test the server using jmeter.It requires a field called database url? Now what i am supposed to fill in that?
Also it is asking for jdbc driver class? What will be the values of these two?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter uses JDBC.

What is your db ? Oracle, mysql ...

Each Db provides drivers you need to put in jmeter/lib folder.

For url each driver has a syntax, examples:

http://www.petefreitag.com/articles/jdbc_urls/

Then you need to add login/password

Comment: My db is mysql. For that i am filling the following fields:                Database url: jdbc:mysql://in.godaddy.com:3306/WhatsGoingOn                                     Driver Class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver                                                                          Username: WhatsGoingOn                                                         Password :*******

Comment: but it is showing 100% error. Is there any mistake that i am doing

Comment: Here WhatsGoingOn is my database as well as username

Answer (score 0):

your database url should be -jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/
database url is the host address of the database u can see that when you connect mysql from gui using SQl yog
 is the database name that you have created in mysql
Your driver class should be -com.mysql.jdbc.driver
user name and password of the database